# Exporting object in file from phone app to computer application

Tags: java, android, file

I am currently making an app where a user will enter information regarding a robotics match and then be 
able to send it to a computer via Bluetooth.
The information they record will be stored in a class called MatchData. I want to write this class as an object in a file, and then send the file over to a computer, to be processed by a computer application. If I have an identical MatchData class on my computer application, with all the same methods and instance variables as the MatchData class on the phone app, will I be able to successfully set my computer side MatchData class to the MatchData class from the phone app?

Sample MatchData class:

```
public class MatchData implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   int pointsScored;
   int matchNumber;

   public MatchData(int points, int matchNumber){
      pointsScored = points;
      this.matchNumber = matchNumber;
   }

   public void addPoint(){
      pointsScored++;
   }

}
```

To test this, I ran a small test on my computer in Eclipse, where I had two completely identical classes called Tester in separate projects. I wrote one of these Tester objects to a file, and then attempted to read that object from a file and set the other Tester object in the separate project to it, but doing so gave me an error, despite the classes being completely identical and implementing Serializable:

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: Tester
```

So, is it possible to export an object in a file from a phone app to a computer and read it? If not, what is the best way to transfer data stored in my MatchData class (there's a lot of data in the class) on a phone to a computer?

Comment: Your life will be much simpler if you use JSON (with Gson and/or Jackson) to do the serialization.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely implement this! So, if I understand correctly, once I serialize all the data in my class using gson/jackson, I can just send the json data as a string over to my computer application, which will deserialize that data?